# (MATLAB/C++) Is it possible to pass functions as arguments to C++ MEX functions?

Tags: c++, matlab, numerical-methods, mex, runge-kutta

I have only been working with mex functions for a couple of weeks, and am now working on writing a Runge-Kutta, 4th order solver as a C++ mex function.
I am wondering whether it is possible to take a function as an input.
Effectively, it would be nice to have my dynamics function written in MATLAB and pass it straight through to my RK4 mex function.
For example, if the dynamics are governed by Duffing's equation, written in MATLAB:

```
function xdot = Duffing(t,x)
xdot = [x(2); 0.3*cos(t)-0.22*x(2)+x(1)-x(1)^3];
end
```

(I do realize this can be written in line as Duffing = @(t,x) (whatever) also)

Is there a way to call the dynamics function from within a mex function or is inputs[] constrained to numeric types only?
I tried the following:

```
class MexFunction : public matlab::mex::Function {
public:
    void operator()(ArgumentList outputs, ArgumentList inputs) {
        
//     Access the dynamics function
        typedef TypedArray<double> xdot_type (TypedArray<double>, TypedArray<double>);
        xdot_type xdot;
        xdot = inputs[0];
```

Naturally, this doesn't work because inputs[0] is not assignable to '`TypedArray<double> (TypedArray<double>, TypedArray<double>)`', since I think the ArgumentList thinks inputs[0] should be purely numeric.
Can anyone think of a solution to this, or will I just have to write my dynamics function in C++?
Looking forward to some suggestions!
Thomas

Comment: Note that the C++ code you tried declared `xdot_type` as a function type, not a function pointer or function object.  Then `xdot_type xdot;` declared a function, not a variable.  And naturally you can't assign to a function at all, no matter what the source type is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just quickly skimming the MATLAB C++ API doc, it looks like you can do this using the matlab::engine::MATLABEngine::feval interface found here:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/cpp-mex-api.html?searchHighlight=fevalAsync&s_tid=srchtitle#mw_723048ca-e22f-4bfb-aa12-47b8007da774

I.e., pass your function name into the C++ mex file as a string which you can get from the ArgumentList via the matlab::data::CharArray syntax:

```
void operator()(matlab::mex::ArgumentList outputs, matlab::mex::ArgumentList inputs) {
    matlab::data::CharArray fname = inputs[0];
    etc.
```

Then convert fname into a std::u16string and use that in the feval interface.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @James's answer, it is also possible using [`coder.extrinsic`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ref/coder.extrinsic.html) within a thin code-generated wrapper layer that sits between the C++ Mex and your Matlab function.

```
              calls                                                     calls
C++ Mex layer ----> Code-Generated Matlab wrapper lib (coder.extrinsic) ----> Matlab function
```

**However, it's probably not a good design**. I assume you are using C++ for performance reasons. Pausing the execution of your program, to marshal data from C++ into Matlab is slow. If you are running a time-stepping simulation, you may find the interop code becomes a performance bottleneck. A better design may be to adapt your *dynamics equation* Matlab code, to make it [code-generatable](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/code-generation.html), then you can invoke the C++ directly from the generated C code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! James's solution actually worked fine, but I agree that the solution may not be optimal. I may be able to generate C code from my MATLAB function, though I'll need to be careful because the dynamics of the plant I am trying to simulate are nonlinear and time-variant (Duffing's equation was provided as an example). Effectively, what I'll end up doing is calling fortran mex functions that model the plant from MATLAB to come up with the differential equations at each time step, then using the RK4 mex function I'm writing right now.

Comment: Though I guess I should still be able to call mexed fortran functions from a generated C-code function right?

Comment: @TGreenhill, yes a Mex is essential a native DLL (C/C++/Fortran) that communicate to Matlab through MxArray objects. It can talk directly to any C/C++ code, without going through an expensive interop layer.